# Using auto vs decltype(vec.size()) in for loop to process vector of strings

Tags: c++, c++17

Teaching myself some of the particulars in using vectors and strings. To do this, I'm taking a paragraph typed into the standard input, storing each word in a separate element in a vector of strings for processing. I understand there may be better ways to actually process text information, I'm just trying to do some exercises to understand more. So, I have a few choices in the loop processing the vector. Two methods I find in my sources are using an `auto` declaration and a `decltype` declaration. The two seem comparable to me but `decltype` is a little bit more clunky and less readable in my eyes. Is there any particular reason to use one vs the other? Is one more advantageous? Is one safer? Or, would there be any advantages/disadvantages to explicitly declaring `size_type` in the loop? Here's a little bit of my code with each for illustration but I'm sure most of you understand what I'm talking about.

```
#import <iostream>
#import <string>
#import <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> vec;
    std::string input;

    while(std::cin >> input)
        vec.push_back(input);

    //auto for loop
    for(auto i = 0; i != vec.size(); ++i)
    {
        //processing
    }

    //decltype for loop
    for(decltype(vec.size()) i = 0; i != vec.size(); ++i)
    {
        //processing
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I didn’t see that one. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with `auto` in this case is it will become `int`, which is signed VS unsigned from `size`. Even though it does not cause any comparison problem due to you use `!=` instead of `<` but you may end up having a problem in the loop if you want to compare with `size` again for some reasons. For the `decltype` version it is overkill for this case. Usually `decltype` will be using with template instead due to it don't know the exact type at that moment. So, the best way for this case should be `unsigned` or `std::size_t` instead.

Comment: The problem with `int` (from auto) is that you get UB if the vector size might exceed `INT_MAX`.  If that can happen then you have a problem with the increment (UB from overflow) and/or the index (UB from negative index).  The comparisons are generally not a problem (though you might get compiler warnings).  Using unsigned is not really any better if it is smaller that size_t, because you then might wrap and the loop never terminate.

Comment: Well that is another problems that less likely to be a problem in this case.

Comment: Sounds like the best thing to do is declare the size_type explicitly